# JQuery Ajax success callback not work when building array of Ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, promise

I need to build an array of objects by resolving an array of promises that was built based on another array.

Let's say I have an array of `letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']`. Then, I map it making Ajax calls using each letter as a param, like this:

```js
var result = letters.map(function (letter) {
    return $.getJSON('myuri', { param: letter });
};
```

As a result, I get an array with ajax promises. Then I resolve it like this:

```js
Promise.all(result).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

The log is printing the original response for every ajax call. Everything works fine until then. But I don't want the original responses, I want custom objects so I've tried using the Ajax's success callbacks to create them, like this:

```js
var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var result = letters.map(function (letter) {
    return $.getJSON('myuri', { param: letter })
            // Chaining with success callback
            .done(function (response) {
                return {
                    'custom_attr': response.x,
                    'athor_custom_attr': response.y
                };
    });
});

Promise.all(result).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

The problem is the success callback doesn't interfere at the array creation. In fact, I can change the return to ANYTHING in the callback and it doesn't make any difference, the code still returns an array of the original responses.

When I did that with Angular using the `$http` service it worked well, but with JQuery using `$.getJSON` doesn't work and I can't understand why this is happening.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: In your `map` function, you are mapping each letter to a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) object. Once your Promise is resolved, I think you'll need to iterate over the `result` array again and map the response data for each jqXHR to the custom object you want.

Comment: But that's what Promise.all is supposed to do. It triggers all promises asynchronously and build the array with each corresponding result.

Comment: [The Promise.all(iterable) method returns a promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved, or rejects with the reason of the first passed promise that rejects.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). So `$.getJSON` returns a promise. So `result` is an array of Promises. `Promise.all(result)` says "Make a promise out of all these promises", so tacking a `.then` there says "when all these promises are done, run this success function." In that function is where you create your custom object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback return value is ignored because you have used `done`. What you actually wanted is to use [`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) which creates a new promise for the result of the callback:

```
var result = letters.map(function (letter) {
    return $.getJSON('myuri', { param: letter })
        .then(function (response) {
            return {
                'custom_attr': response.x,
                'athor_custom_attr': response.y
            };
        });
});
```

**The `done` method is not chainable!** There is hardly ever a reason to use it over `then`.

Comment: It worked! I've used `then` before and the result was the same. But now I simply worked. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know `done` was not chainable .Thanks!

Comment: @romellem: Well, technically you can chain more method calls to it since it returns the promise it was called on, but it's not chainable in the monadic sense.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, I think you just need to map the response data for each jqXHR to the custom object you want.

So something like:

```
Promise.all(result).then(function (response) {
    result = response.map(function(c) {
        return {
            'custom_attr': c.x,
            'another_custom_attr': c.y
        };
    });
});
```

This is assuming `var result;` was declared in a scope that would be accessible here.

---

Here's a full sample:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<button class="load-ajax">Click To Make our AJAX calls!</button>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
// Declare `result` in global scope.
var result;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.load-ajax').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
        result = letters.map(function (letter) {
            return $.getJSON('json.php', { param: letter });
        });

        Promise.all(result).then(function (response) {
            result = response.map(function(c) {
                return { "custom_attr" : c.param };
            });
            console.log("DONE! Look at `result`");
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And the sample `json.php` file:

```
<?php
// json.php
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode($_GET);
?>
```

So, at the end of the day, `result` is equal to:

```
[
  {custom_attr: "a"},
  {custom_attr: "b"},
  {custom_attr: "c"}
]
```

Comment: I tried your code and iterating again solved the problem too. But I'd like to avoid having to iterate again, specially because in Angular I didn't need to do it and I was wondering why with JQuery I would. Thank you!